# Java parse a string using a scanner, and using the parsed string as input in an if else statement

Tags: java, parsing, if-statement, java.util.scanner, turtle-graphics

Hello fellow programmers! I am a Java beginner and I need some help.

I have a program that I want to make the Turtle move using prefabricated instructions in a string called "rule". I want that rule to be parsed into a readable format for an if-else statement. The if-else statement will then read every character in the parsed "rule", and make the Turtle move accordingly to each condition.

I have ran into some issues with the program, it parses (I think so) and displays the rule, but there is no movement from the turtle. I believe it has something to do with the if-else statement. Please help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class FractalEngine
{

    World worldObj = new World();
    Turtle m = new Turtle(200, 200, worldObj);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    FractalEngine()
    {

        //String rule = "F-F+F+F-FQ";
        String rule = "F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-FQ"; 
        //String rule = "F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-FQ";

        m.setHeading(0);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(rule);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Fractal Rule: ");
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine()); 
        System.out.println();

        // it prints it to the terminal, but no Turtle movement. Am I using the right parsing method?

        do
        {
            Scanner scanRule = new Scanner(rule);
            scanRule.nextLine();

            if(rule.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
                m.forward(25);
            else if(rule.equals("-"))
                m.turnLeft();
            else if(rule.equals("+"))
                m.turnRight();
            else
                rule = "Q";       

        }
        while(!rule.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));

        System.out.println("Fractal construction terminated.");

    }   
}

public class FractalConstructor
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    FractalEngine fe = new FractalEngine();

}
}
```

Comment: Please include your output. Hint: assign the result of `nextLine()` to a variable. And you probably don't want to use a `Scanner`, but instead convert `rule` to a character array.

Comment: You don't really need to use a `Scanner` to do what you want, unless you want to read from some other source than a prefabricated String later.
You can simple do `char[] commands = rule.toCharArray()` and then loop through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried that script, and it works for me it prints each action depends on the command , So I think the problem is in your functions I mean  (m.forward(), m.turnRight()...)

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String rule = "F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F+F-F+F+F-F-F-F+F+F-FQ";


    int i = 0 ;
    char[] cmds = rule.toCharArray();
    do
    {
        if(cmds[i] == 'F') {
            System.out.println("Foward");
        }
        else if(cmds[i] == '-') {
            System.out.println("Left");
        }
        else if(cmds[i] == '+') {
            System.out.println("Right");
        }
        else // it's surely "Q"
            break ; 
        i++ ;
    }
    while(true);
    System.out.println("Fractal construction terminated.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lot of code logic issues, you may change your do while loop with code bellow

```
        boolean done = false;
        String line ;
        while((line = scanner.nextLine()) != null && !done)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i< rule.length(); i++) {
                if(rule.charAt(i) == 'F')
                    m.forward(25);
                else if(rule.charAt(i) == '-')
                    m.turnLeft();
                else if(rule.charAt(i) == '+' )
                    m.turnRight();
                else{
                    done = true; 
                    break; 
                }
            }
        }
```